# SWFUpload is it possible to upload multiple files to a single php script execution

Tags: php, javascript, upload, swfupload

I'm trying to implement SWFUpload into an existing PHP upload funcitonality. My current backend script however expects 2 fiels to be uploaded in a single php script execution. (e.g. it excepts the $_FILES parameters to contain 2 entries).

So i'm queueing 2 files with SWFUpload and start uploading them. However it appears SWFLUpload calls the php backend script for each queued file.

I'd rather modify SWFUpload to send the files with a single backend script execution instead on having to adjust the backend script.

Is anyone familiar with this? I've searched various resources (like the SWFUploads docs and forum, but have not found similiar topics.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know that the API being used in Flash allows for this, but don't know whether this is exposed by SWFUpload.

Comment: Yeah, I looked up the Flash API and it allows this indeed. I suppose ill give the SWFUpload forum a try, since this is a very specific SWFUpload issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Kwaak! Please clarify were you able to find a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. This may help you.

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/

All the best

Answer (score 0):

SWFUpload does it .
Here is the link:
http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/simpledemo/index.php
you can choose several files at a time.
take care